# Why I'm unable to debug my code in TestNG

Tags: java, debugging, testng

I am running automation tests using TestNG and Java.

Here is part of my code:

```
private void testConnection(String URL1) throws IOException {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(URL1);
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConn.connect();

        assertEquals(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, urlConn.getResponseCode());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        ConsoleLogger.error("*******************************");
        ConsoleLogger.error("Could NOT connect to the server");
        ConsoleLogger.error("Entire test is aborted!!!");
        ConsoleLogger.error("Please check port and IP again!");
        ConsoleLogger.error("*******************************");
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Now, my test fails because I am getting an exception from the URL.
I can see in the console the error message/s.
This method is being called in a method with the annotation @BeforeSuite.

Why can’t I debug this method (not the try block nor the catch block)?

Comment: is it actually called? why do you assume you can't debug it?

Comment: I know my code works because I see the errors in the console. I placed breakpoints and didn't hit them.

Comment: What does it mean that you can not debug?

Comment: @YishaiSeela simply adding breakpoints is not debugging

Comment: If the break points are not being hit, then that code is not executed.

Comment: which editor you using ?? . or in some cases, the setup is not been cleaned up and retains. make sure you close all open connections and rerun the code.

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4. I'm running the code in debug mode but I'm not hitting the breakpoints. My code has been executed as I see the text I wrote in the catch block on my console.

Comment: Does it work if you place a breakpoint somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

You've mentioned that your breakpoints are not being respected by IntelliJ and I can see from your code that there are references to a server. This might be happening if you are trying to do remote debugging:

> To debug your code on a server you have to attach your debugger to its debug port. This means starting the server in debug mode, and creating a Remote debugging run configuration in IntelliJ attached to the correct port (which should be reported in your server initialisation logging).

For more information read the the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36179503/5759072).

If you are not remote debugging you can try do to the following:

- Clear your cache with File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart.
- Delete your whole project folder and import it again.
- Reinstall your IDE and delete all configurations.

I was assuming you are working in IntelliJ for some reason but all of these points should work for other programs as well.

Comment: I don't think he is trying to debug a remote process. Just because he is making an http call is not a symptom at all that he is trying to debug something remotely.

Comment: We don't know that, and his symptom of not being able to use breakpoints is consistent with remote debugging, so it's safe to assume that that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can print out the error message, definitely you have chance to debug. You can try to set break point at that printing error message. If it still fail. Means your workspace is not update with your code. Just refresh or restart your IDE. Good luck.